# Choosing the right paypal billing option

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

On my site, I have multiple billing plans, for example:

- 1$ = 5  points
- 2$ = 15 points
- 3$ = 30 points

When user chooses paypal option, I want him to be redirected to the paypal checkout page, 
and on completion of transaction, I want to receive notification so I can grand the account
with points. I understand that can't be done with Pay Now button. Also, I can't understand what is the most right way to do so. Suggestion?

- when i talk about paypal checkout page I mean this one

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a drop down menu option to allow the buyer to select which one they are wanting to purchase.  Then that will popluate the PayPal checkout page with the correct options selected, and amount.  As for getting the information back to your site.  I would use IPN.

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.

Checkout this page [here for more on IPN](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro).  There are also some samples of IPN scripts, and additional links relating to IPN on the left hand side of that page.